# Flutter stable 1.17.1 and Xcode 11.5 issues

Tags: xcode, flutter

After upgrading to Flutter 1.17.1 and Xcode 11.5, I cannot build for iOS anymore.
Despite following all the direction in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

Anyone faces the same issue? Any solution?

```
flutter doctor
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-SG)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin version 12.1 - the recommended minimum version is 16.0.0
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Here is the output when I do
flutter run

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Your Xcode project requires migration. See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration for details.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 0):

Came from 1.13=>1.17. It did not upgrade my project automatically so I had to work a bit in Xcode. I solved the issue by executing all steps listed on the migration page. Then executing:

```
rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework
rm -rf ios/Pod*
flutter clean
```

Build and run => success

Answer (score 0):

[image: Remove These]

Yes, in addition, I have to remove the above.

thanks